# Changing order of draw operation in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I've developed a pgfplots ybar chart with white horizontal grid lines over the vertical bars to help the reader judge the length of the bars. The "base" of the ybar chart (the x-axis) is set to y=1 so that I can see whether the normalized results are above or below the axis at y=1. My problem is that I'm having trouble drawing the black x-axis line at y=1 without it being overwritten by a white grid line.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
    Cat A, 1.06
    Cat B, 0.92
    Cat C, 1.01
    Cat D, 1.04
    Cat E, 0.88
}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, 
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    height=4cm,
    ymax=0.125,
    ymin=-0.125,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
    xtick=data,
    ytick={-0.1,-0.05,...,0.1},
    yticklabels={0.90,0.95,1.00,1.05,1.10},
    ytick pos=left,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    major grid style={thin,color=white},        
    axis on top,
    ylabel={Normalized value},
    x axis line style={draw opacity=0},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    xticklabel style={
        rotate=90, 
        anchor=east,
    }
]
    \addplot [fill=black,draw=none] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=\thisrowno{1}-1] {\datatable};
    \draw [black,thin] (rel axis cs:0,0.5) -- (rel axis cs:1,0.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: clip1]

If I remove `axis on top`, the x-axis is drawn correctly, but then I lose the white grid lines over the vertical bars.

[image: clip2]

How can I change my plot such that the x-axis is drawn last or in such a way that it is drawn on top of the grid line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `set layers` feature. Then you simply need to draw the black line on the top most layer ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotstableread[
            col sep=comma,
            header=false,
        ]{
            Cat A, 1.06
            Cat B, 0.92
            Cat C, 1.01
            Cat D, 1.04
            Cat E, 0.88
        }\datatable
    \begin{axis}[
        set layers,          % <-- added
        ybar,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        height=4cm,
        ymax=0.125,
        ymin=-0.125,
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
        xtick=data,
        ytick={-0.1,-0.05,...,0.1},
        yticklabels={0.90,0.95,1.00,1.05,1.10},
        ytick pos=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        major grid style={thin,color=white},
        axis on top,
        ylabel={Normalized value},
        x axis line style={draw opacity=0},
        xtick style={draw=none},
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
        },
    ]
        \addplot [fill=black,draw=none] table [
            x expr=\coordindex,
            y expr=\thisrowno{1}-1,
        ] {\datatable};

        \pgfonlayer{axis foreground}
            \draw [black,thin] (rel axis cs:0,0.5) -- (rel axis cs:1,0.5);
        \endpgfonlayer
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat a workaround

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
    Cat A, 1.06
    Cat B, 0.92
    Cat C, 1.01
    Cat D, 1.04
    Cat E, 0.88
}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, 
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    height=4cm,
    ymax=0.125,
    ymin=-0.125,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
    xtick=data,
    ytick={-0.1,-0.05,...,0.1},
    yticklabels={0.90,0.95,1.00,1.05,1.10},
    ytick pos=left,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    major grid style={thin,color=white},        
    axis on top,
    ylabel={Normalized value},
    x axis line style={draw opacity=0},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    xticklabel style={
        rotate=90, 
        anchor=east,
    }
]
    \addplot [fill=black,draw=none] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=\thisrowno{1}-1] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\draw (rel axis cs:0.2,0.5) -- (rel axis cs:1.1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]